# Find a value and replace with value*2 in the same file

Tags: python, file

I have ColumnLength  in the text file which needs to be converted to be like (ColumnLength*2)

> Actual : ( DDL.txt)
> [1:[ColumnName:'ACCOUNT_CATEGORY__C',ColumnLength:'20',ColumnType:'CV'],
> [2:[ColumnName:'ACCOUNT_CATEGORY__C',ColumnLength:'50',ColumnType:'I'],
>
> Expected : ( DDL.txt)
> [1:[ColumnName:'ACCOUNT_CATEGORY__C',ColumnLength:'**40**',ColumnType:'CV'],
> [2:[ColumnName:'ACCOUNT_CATEGORY__C',ColumnLength:'**100**',ColumnType:'I'],

Comment: What did you try so far ? Post some code.

Comment: file = open('D:\DDL.txt','r')
#print(file.readlines())
for i in file.readlines():
    if(i.find('ColumnLength',0)) >= 0:
        startpos = 0
        endpos = 0
        print(i)
        startpos = i.find("'")
        endpos = i.find("'",startpos+1)
        print('String value is',i[startpos+1:endpos])

Answer (score 0):

I can not find a way doing in shell script.so I do it in python

```py
import re
pattern = re.compile("ColumnLength:'(\d+)'")
with open("DDL.txt","r+") as f:
    content = f.read()
    lines = content.split('],')
    new_lines = []
    for line in lines:
        if line.strip()=='':
            continue
        find = pattern.findall(line)
        
        line = pattern.sub("ColumnLength:'%s'" % (int(find[0])*2),line)
        new_lines.append(line)

    content = "], ".join(new_lines) + "]"
    f.write(content)
```

Comment: Many Thanks for the solution however its doesnt get updated with new value ...after code run column length value remains the same